# Display information from Stripe response in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Connect and I have a few connected accounts.

I can retrieve a balance of an account but cannot echo the values. This is what I have:

```
     $current_user_stripe_id = "acct_XXXXXXXXXX";

      $balance = \Stripe\Balance::retrieve(
                    ["stripe_account" => $current_user_stripe_id]
                  );

      echo $balance;
```

Which successfully returns this:

```
Stripe\Balance JSON: { "object": "balance", "available": [ { "amount": 0, "currency": "gbp", "source_types": { "card": 0 } } ], "livemode": false, "pending": [ { "amount": 2213, "currency": "gbp", "source_types": { "card": 2213 } } ] }
```

**However**

Trying to access the json in object  fashion throws an error:

```
$pending_balance = $balance->pending->amount;
echo $pending_balance;
```

I've tried json_decode($balance) too with no luck.

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Hi, welcome. I suggest you expand upon what you have tried and what the results were.

Comment: Welcome aboard :) Looks like `pending` is an array of objects. Perhaps `$balance->pending[0]->amount` would work.

Comment: Thank you @m_katsifarakis - $balance->pending[0]->amount has worked!!